# Pagination base URL - any way to have pagination links go to URLs other than current one?

Tags: entries, pagination

TL;DR: Looking for something like [paginate_base](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/templates/pagination.html#paginate-base) parameter in EE, but for Craft.

My site's homepage has content in tabs for different sections (news, products, etc.) and in each tab I would like to have pagination links that would go to 2nd, 3rd, etc page in each section.

So in News tab I display news entries and would like to link to /news/p2, /news/p3 etc, on Products tab I would have links to /products/p2, /products/p3 etc. All that on same page, with URL different from /news or /products

Is there any way to achieve that in Craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but I would assume that you could simply get the total entries, divide by the pagination limit and then generate your dynamic nav using a range loop.

```
{% set totalEntries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(null).total() %}
{% set pageLimit = 10 %}
{% set totalPages = (totalEntries / pageLimit)|round(0, 'ceil') %}

<ul>
    {% for i in range(1, totalPages) %}
        <li><a href="/news/p{{ i }}"></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Good idea and might work in some cases (having replaced `find()` with total()`)  - but does not really work for me as the increment in `for` is adding 1, while it needs to add `pageLimit` - and if I add `pageLimit` as 3rd parameter for `range` I get `range(): step exceeds the specified range` error as initially number of entries is less then number of item per page. I need to get this done on Craft level, not on Twig level.

Comment: Just to be clear `pageLimit` is the limit that you have defined for your elementCriteriaModel used by the pagination tag on the target page (i.e. on the news page). So by definition `totalEntries/pageLimit` rounded up should represent the total number of pages. The only other task is to create the same number of links as pages — thus the `range` loop. What is not working?

Comment: You're right, I just did not apply parameter to `total()` that I have in my entries loop, and so was getting unexpectable results. Your answer works, I only changed it to `range(2, totalPages)` (as I don't need first page) and  added `{% if totalEntries > pageLimit %}` because otherwise range is counting in reverse direction. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked. fyi... i updated answer with your `.total()` suggestion — much cleaner and probably saves some memory. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 3.1.28, you can set base URL of pagination links, like this:

```
{% paginate query as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
{% do pageInfo.setBasePath('new_url') %}
```